# Upload option unavailable in Page Library - Sharepoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have recently become an admin for a sharepoint-online(O365 cloud) space.

I am not able to figure out how to enable upload in Page Library. We have many aspx pages that we want to upload here in the Page Library.

Please note that drag and drop also doesn't seem to work.

Can someone help me out with the steps to enable the Page Library upload option?

[image: No Upload Option in Page Library]

Comment: Are you a site collection admin for this?  If not, become one. You will have much greater insight into your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, uploading pages in the modern Page library is not available.

As a workaround, you could return to classic Page library then upload.

Comment: ahh this works.. Do you know how to make it available in the modern Page Library? Some permission to be set or something else needs to be done?

Comment: By design, uploading pages in the modern Page library is not available.

Comment: Going to classing mode solved my problem for now.